# How to connent wordpress with a database base on server

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I'm newbiee with `wordpress` , I installed `wordpress` with a new `database` where `local host` as `hostname` and `username` as `abc123` , `database` as `abc`, `password` as `abc` according to it .

I tried with plugin like wp- business intelligence and cutomizr theme and i generated the tablke using query `[wpbusinessintelligence id="1" type ="table"] Details [/wpbusinessintelligence]`.

Now my requirement is , I have xyz database and its not in local host its in `167.**.**.**`, but when i try to follow the same steps with new folder for new report i get an error message like:

> error with database connection

May i know where i'm going wrong and what steps should i follow .

Answer (score 1):

You need to make changes to the wp-config.php file. This will be in folder that wordpress is installed in on the server.

There is also a wp-config-sample.php file, in the same folder, in case you make any mistakes and need to start again.

In the file there are settings for your database - so that the wordpress installation can communicate with the database ont eh server. these are the parameters you need to change.

Below is a copy of the file. You need to change the values in lower case in '' . 
For example, I believe that you should set

```
define('DB_NAME', 'xyz');

define('DB_USER', 'username_here');  // change  username_here
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'password_here');  // change password_here


    // ** MySQL settings - You can get this info from your web host ** //
/** The name of the database for WordPress */
define('DB_NAME', 'blue');

/** MySQL database username */
define('DB_USER', 'daniel');

/** MySQL database password */
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'daniel');

/** MySQL hostname */
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');

/** Database Charset to use in creating database tables. */
define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');

/** The Database Collate type. Don't change this if in doubt. */
define('DB_COLLATE', '');
```

Then save the file and the database should make the connection and run wordpress.